# Give a Array a Different Name in base of a string

Tags: python

As you read in the title, I want to give to an array a specific name in base of another string variable in Python.
Im new to python but I already know JS

Here's a piece of my code:

```
bot = Bot()
chosenusers = bot.read_list_from_file(args.filepath) #enderlxxvii

if not chosenusers:
    exit()
else:
    print("Found %d users in file." % len(chosenusers))

bot.login(username=args.u, password=args.p, proxy=args.proxy)

bot.follow_users(chosenusers)
for x in chosenusers:
    followers = bot.get_user_followers(x)  #Array
```

I want the array to be called enderlxxviifollowers or something similar
I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: You want to rename the variable?

Comment: @Jonathan1609 yes, but I want it to be enderlxxviifollowers or whatever is in the txt file

Comment: ok i will write a generic answer

Comment: Changing the variable name dynamically is definitely an anti-pattern. Could you explain in more detail why you think you would need to change its name? If you want to associate a arbitrary string to a value, then you can use a `dict` instead. But what's the problem with having just an generic variable name in this case?

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman yes, i don’t have to change the name btw I I want to use a dynamic variable name that change in base of the account name.

Comment: Yeah, but why? You use variables to refer to data in your application. By creating variables dynamically you can't reliably refer to the value anywhere in your code, as it'll have different name every time the program is run. This is something that **will** cause you problems in the future. Having a variable name `chosen_users` that refers to the currently fetch users is definitely the preferred solution.

Comment: Thank you for the advice :) I badly explained, the script just get the followers of a determinated accounts in an array, how can I store these arrays and get them later ? The accounts are written in a txt file. Thank you, i hope I’m not annoying

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. The array of followers is currently stored in the variable `chosen_users` and can be referenced with that variable, as long as the program is still running. Or do you mean store as in storing them back into the file? Is that what you mean by getting them later; the next time you run the program?

Comment: ``chosenusers`` is an array that contains the accounts (imported from a txt file) to get the followers from. In the example, chosenusers contains only my Username, enderlxxvii. With the method .get_Users_Followers() you get an array that contains the IDs of the accounts followed by the “main account” (enderlxxvii in my case). I’ll have differents account to get the followers from, and I want to store the array in differents array, because I need them later

Comment: Okay, that sounds like you want a dictionary, i.e. a mapping between a name (in your case a user) with an array of followers. A dictionary in python is very much like a JSON. You can create it with`followers = { name: bot.get_user_followers(name) for name in chosen_users }`. This allow you to the use the `dict` to get the array of all followers by using `followers['enderlxxvii']` or `followers[username]` where `username` is a variable containing the user you want to get the array from.

Comment: Thank you mate ! I’m gonna this morning! It’s 2am here.

Answer (score 1):

A general answer to this case is:

`globals()["new_var_name"] = old_var_name`

you can obtain the new_var_name from whereever you want, assuming that's what you are looking for.

Comment: While this is a correct way to change a variable name, I highly doubt that this is ever a solution to any common problem. It seems like the asker rather should use a dictionary to map a string to an array.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman yes it seemed weird to me as well XD